# python33.dll not found in my Python installation path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I'm trying to build the `libpython33.a` file so I can create my own C extensions using MinGW. For that, I need the `python33.dll` file to create a `.def` file and then convert that to the finally `libpython33.a`.

In my Python 2.7 installation, I can see the file called `python27.dll` along with `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`. But in the Python 3 folder I there's no DLLs. In the Python3/DLLs folder there's a file called `python3.dll` (not `python33.dll`).

Is my Python instalation damaged or that's ok?

Comment: I don't have that. Do you have it?

Comment: [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython) has libpython33.a for 64-bit. As an answer points out, the DLL is probably in `%windir%\System32` if you installed for all users, if you'd rather build the archive yourself.

Comment: That saves me some work, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python33.dll` is found under `c:\windows\system32`